# Python create limited type

Tags: python, type-hinting

I have a python function that I want to accept one of 5 possible values. These values are: "Q", 1, 2, 3, and 4. Yes, that is a string and 4 integers. Is there a way to create an object which I can use in type hinting to specify only one of these 5 values? The following will clearly not work, but it has the gist of what I'm looking for in defining an object which a variable of that type can only be one of the 5 values listed above. Is this even possible?

```py
PlayoffRound = ["Q", 1, 2, 3, 4]  # or some other way to define an object with only these possibilities
def func(playoff_round: PlayoffRound) -> None:
    # do something
    pass
```

Comment: Please explain clearly what you mean by "create an object which I can use in type hinting to specify only one of these 5 values".  How would you use this object?

Comment: @ewokx the apparent intent is to *define a type for a third-party static type checker*, such that it will reject code that calls the function with a value outside of that set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are describing what [`typing.Literal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Literal) does:

```
from typing import Literal

PlayoffRound = Literal["Q", 1, 2, 3, 4]

def func(playoff_round: PlayoffRound) -> None:
    pass
```